# Selenium web driver does throws chrome errors node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My selenium web driver throws errors no matter what I do, I am running ubuntu docker, it has java installed and I installed google chrome as the last resort.

No matter what I do, I get errors. I tried running it with `headless-chrome (v86)` combined with `chromedriver v 86`, with `selenium-webdriver node version 4.10`.

If I use that, chrome just hangs on first `webDriver.get(**)` command.

```
WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: unable to discover open pages)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Playing arround with configuration, no matter how I run it, it either throws

- chrome crashed randomly. (Not responding)
- chrome not reachable.
- or version issues.
- (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)

But to my understanding If technically Id use selenium 4.10 node. Chrome 114 and chromedriver 114, it should work. I am running headless, my arguments for running chrome are:

```
            '--headless=new',
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-browser-side-navigation',
            '--disable-dev-s1hm-usage',
            '--single-process',
```

Tried playing around with these, to no victory it always drops errors with chrome.

My setup code:

```js
const $webDriver = new selenium_webdriver_1.Builder()
    .forBrowser(selenium_webdriver_1.Browser.CHROME)
    .setChromeService(new chrome_1.ServiceBuilder((0, path_1.join)(__dirname, 'headless', 'chromedriver')))
    // .withCapabilities({'browserName': 'Chrome', 'pageLoadStrategy': 'eager'})
    .setChromeOptions(new chrome_1.Options()
        .setChromeBinaryPath((0, path_1.join)(__dirname, 'headless', 'headless-chromium'))
        // .headless()
        .addArguments(
            // 'start-maximized',
            // 'enable-automation',
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--headless=new',
            '--no-sandbox',
            // '--disable-browser-side-navigation',
            // '--disable-dev-s1hm-usage',
            '--single-process',
            // '--disable-extensions',
            // '--dns-prefetch-disable',
            // 'disable-features=NetworkService',
            // "--force-device-scale-factor=1",
            // '--window-size=1280x1696', // Letter size
            // '--log-level=0',
            // '--ignore-certificate-errors'
        )
    )
    .build();
```